# Get list of friends above the messenger in Facebook with Graph Api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I stuck on finding a way to get the list of friends above the messenger :

[image]

This list contains the "most used friends" in facebook messenger...

Facebook give us a way to get these information ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API which returns the list of friends visible at the top of the chat window on Facebook.com

Comment: Thank you, feel free to inform me if there are changes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook chat does not use standard Graph Api, it uses XMPP protocol instead. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) you can find facebook documentation. As far as I know you can get list of active friends in XMPP, you can get more info about xmpp roster [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Protocol-XMPP/lib/Protocol/XMPP/IQ/Roster.pm). The best way to implement this is to use some open source XMPP libraries. There is [official list](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) so use one of those.

You should also note that "Your Facebook Chat integration should only be used for sessions that are expected to be long-lived. Clients should not rapidly churn on and off." The chat API is meant to be used for chat. With that in mind consider if you are really going to use that api for a long term session.